# During startup r - Setting LC_COLLATE failed, using "C"

Tags: r

Setup:
- OS X 10.10.4
- R: 3.2.1 "World-Famous Astronaut"
Start iTerm, start R,
Start R runs to an Warning message:

[image: Warning Message Screenshot]
//

- Whats missing? gcc?
- R, X11 & gcc installed via brew.
- Anyone?

`print(Sys.getenv())`

[Output for print(Sys.getenv())](http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/24MU)

Comment: there is no .Rprofile ;)

Maybe this problem caused other problems - eg. ERROR Install RPostgreSQL
![Screenshot] (http://d.pr/i/8IYh)

Comment: @hrbrmstr the same 4 Errors

Comment: I update to 3.2.2 (2015-08-14) -- "Fire Safety"
but the "Warning messages" are still the same.

Comment: Can you paste the output (not screen shot) of `echo "print(Sys.getenv())" | R --vanilla` into the question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem like yours.
I just type in terminal:

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

and then I checked if it made changes by typing "locale".
If you get script like this:

```
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
```

Then your problem is solved.
Just check if the warning is gone by typing "R" in terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and following the previous answer, it was solved. However, you need to export to C based on your error screenshot:

```
export LC_COLATE=C
export LC_TIME=C
export LC_MESSAGES=C
export LC_MONETARY=C
```